# How can I get notebook fields in my view calendar?

Tags: xml, calendar, odoo, field

I want to create a calendar view in Odoo, where the fields to be displayed are from a notebook. In other words, my fields are related to a relational field in the relationship:

```
class PlanificationRotatio(models.Model):
    _name = 'plannification.rotation'
    
    rotation_ids = fields.One2many('relation.rotation', inverse_name='planification_rotation', string="Rotation")
```

```
class PlanifictaionRelation(models.Model):
    _name = 'relation.rotation'

    planification_rotation = fields.Many2one('plannification.rotation')
    ettats = fields.Selection([('suggestion', 'Suggestion'),
                               ('valide', 'Validé')], string='États', default="suggestion")
    sequence = fields.Char('sequence')
    vehicule = fields.Many2one('fleet.vehicle', string=" Vehicules libres", readonly="True")
    is_selected = fields.Boolean('Selection')
    chauffeur = fields.Char('Chauffeur')
    zone = fields.Char('Zone')
```

My xml code:

```
<record id="view_planfication_rotation_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">planification.rotation.calendar</field>
         <field name="model">plannification.rotation</field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <calendar string="Planification" date_start="date_sortie" color="states" hide_time="true" event_limit="5">
                    <field name="states" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="rotation_ids">
                         <calendar>
                             <field name="chauffeur"/>
                             <field name="vehicule"/>
                         </calendar>
                    </field>
                </calendar>
         </field>
     </record>
```

I am facing an issue where the calendar view is not displaying any data or information. It appears empty. I would appreciate any assistance or guidance to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The thing it's that you haven't provide any of the needed configuration so the calendar view could show the `relation.rotation` records in the calendar view.
You need to have some date or datetime fields to be able to use them as Calendar Events. At least you need to define `date_start` like this:

```xml
<field name="rotation_ids">
     <calendar date_start="create_date">
         <field name="chauffeur"/>
         <field name="vehicule"/>
     </calendar>
</field>
```

See that I have used the automatic field `create_date` because I haven't saw any Date or Datetime field in your `relation.rotation` model

Comment: @ aieskis.dev i tried what you have said, but nothing changed,
actually i want to display in my view calendar that i should  create in my model"plannification.rotation" the following fields:  chauffeur , vehicule, zone, sequence that are fileds of an other model , so i dont know what shall i do exactly, can you help me please

Comment: you haven't saw any date or datetime field in my relation.retation cause it doesn't contain them , it contain only zone, chauffeur, vehicule, sequence, and by adding them it return an error that says this field does not exist,

Comment: I will need more to work with around your scenario. If you wanna send me an email in order to coordinate a consulting session to look at your issue in more detail, perhaps I could reproduce it in my local and give you an exact solution

Comment: @aiekus.dev  may i have your adress mail pls

Comment: it's axel@aekis.dev or see it on my profile here

Comment: I will do it right now

Comment: @aeksis.dev i sent it.

Comment: You sent me an incomplete module. I have tried to full the gaps but It won't install

Comment: okey sorry i will resend right now

Comment: Hope that you have received the email.